# Crashes on first picture

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Doing nothing fancy, i start the app, take a picture, I can see that the native camera app takes longer to let me confirm the picture, then i press save and the app goes back to my index (crashes)

This is the catlog from i click take picture till i press save:

```
12-11 00:17:54.727: V/webview(13180):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
12-11 00:17:55.147: D/DroidGap(13180): Paused the application!
12-11 00:17:55.147: D/CordovaWebView(13180): Handle the pause
12-11 00:17:56.222: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13180): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-11 00:17:56.657: D/webviewglue(13180): OnTrimMemory with EGL Context 0x532a1698
12-11 00:17:57.337: D/webviewglue(13180): OnTrimMemory with EGL Context 0x0
12-11 00:17:57.377: E/libEGL(13180): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
12-11 00:17:57.392: E/SQLiteLog(13180): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-11 00:17:57.392: E/SQLiteLog(13180): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/GeolocationPermissions.db) - 
12-11 00:17:57.392: D/WebKit(13180): ERROR: 
12-11 00:17:57.397: D/WebKit(13180): SQLite database failed to load from /GeolocationPermissions.db
12-11 00:17:57.397: D/WebKit(13180): Cause - unable to open database file
12-11 00:17:57.397: D/WebKit(13180): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
12-11 00:18:00.957: E/Trace(14212): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-11 00:18:01.147: I/webclipboard(14212): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42cdbb90
12-11 00:18:01.197: I/CordovaLog(14212): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
12-11 00:18:01.197: I/CordovaLog(14212): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
12-11 00:18:01.197: D/CordovaLog(14212): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
12-11 00:18:01.197: I/CordovaLog(14212): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
12-11 00:18:01.197: D/CordovaLog(14212): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
12-11 00:18:01.207: D/JsMessageQueue(14212): Set native->JS mode to 2
12-11 00:18:01.207: D/DroidGap(14212): DroidGap.init()
12-11 00:18:01.222: D/CordovaWebView(14212): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-11 00:18:01.222: D/PluginManager(14212): init()
12-11 00:18:01.227: D/CordovaWebView(14212): >>> loadUrlNow()
12-11 00:18:01.232: D/DroidGap(14212): Resuming the App
12-11 00:18:01.242: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(14212): Ignore this event
12-11 00:18:01.272: V/webkit(14212): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42cd27e0}
12-11 00:18:01.297: D/libEGL(14212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-11 00:18:01.307: D/libEGL(14212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-11 00:18:01.307: D/libEGL(14212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-11 00:18:01.312: D/(14212): Device driver API match
12-11 00:18:01.312: D/(14212): Device driver API version: 10
12-11 00:18:01.312: D/(14212): User space API version: 10 
12-11 00:18:01.312: D/(14212): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
12-11 00:18:01.337: D/dalvikvm(14212): GC_CONCURRENT freed 283K, 7% free 12291K/13127K, paused 17ms+13ms, total 50ms
12-11 00:18:01.352: D/OpenGLRenderer(14212): Enabling debug mode 0
12-11 00:18:01.352: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(14212): Ignore this event
12-11 00:18:01.407: D/DroidGap(14212): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-11 00:18:01.407: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(14212): Ignore this event
12-11 00:18:01.872: D/CordovaLog(14212): Uncaught Function required as first argument!
12-11 00:18:01.872: D/CordovaLog(14212): file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova.js: Line 546 : Uncaught Function required as first argument!
12-11 00:18:01.872: E/Web Console(14212): Uncaught Function required as first argument!:546
12-11 00:18:01.997: I/GATE(14212): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
12-11 00:18:01.997: D/Cordova(14212): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-11 00:18:01.997: D/DroidGap(14212): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
12-11 00:18:01.997: D/DroidGap(14212): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-11 00:18:02.047: E/SQLiteLog(14212): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-11 00:18:02.047: E/SQLiteLog(14212): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
12-11 00:18:02.047: D/WebKit(14212): ERROR: 
12-11 00:18:02.047: D/WebKit(14212): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
12-11 00:18:02.047: D/WebKit(14212): Cause - unable to open database file
12-11 00:18:02.047: D/WebKit(14212): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
12-11 00:18:02.117: D/DroidGap(14212): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
12-11 00:18:02.137: D/DroidGap(14212): onMessage(spinner,stop)
12-11 00:18:02.187: D/TilesManager(14212): new EGLContext from framework: 52dea530 
12-11 00:18:02.187: D/GLWebViewState(14212): Reinit shader
12-11 00:18:02.217: D/GLWebViewState(14212): Reinit transferQueue
12-11 00:18:03.997: D/DroidGap(14212): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

If you need to see any code, i will provide it.